# Download file hosted on a website

Tags: java, android, download

I am trying to download a file that I have hosted on mega. The code is as follows:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LoggerDebug.d("Prakhar", "Inside run");
                try {
                    URL downloadUrl = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadUrl.openConnection();

                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                    httpURLConnection.connect();

                    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File downloadFile = new File(SDCardRoot, "downloaded.zip");

                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                    int totalSize = httpURLConnection.getContentLength();
                    int downloadedSize = 0;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bufferLength = 0;

                    LoggerDebug.d("Prakhar", String.valueOf(totalSize));
                    while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                        LoggerDebug.d("Prakhar", String.valueOf(downloadedSize));
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Now after I run this code sample I get the following:

Total size is : -1
Downloaded size : 1024
On the mobile I can see the `downloaded.zip` file, its size is `1.97KB` and the original size of the upload is `87.1KB`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you missed `fileOutputStream.close()` after the end of the while loop. Do you have the permission to write into `SDCardRoot`?

Comment: I'd also `flush()` the stream, before closing it.

Comment: @Blackbelt I have the permission to write, yes.

Comment: And no change. Still the same after implementing the 2 lines suggested.

Comment: Have you tried the code outside of mega?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider not yet, will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if you solved your problem yet, but I can see a couple potential issues.

1. `setDoOutput(true)` indicates you're going to be uploading according to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Specifically, it says:

> To upload data to a web server, configure the connection for output using `setDoOutput(true).`

You're not uploading from what I'm seeing, so this isn't needed, and it's unclear how the server would respond since it appears you're requesting the ability to upload.

2. A return of -1 indicates an EOF. You're not accessing the file you're intending to, likely due to #3.
3. You probably can't just download from their site willy-nilly. You need to authenticate somehow. This could be an API key, session id, yadda yadda. They have their own API, and according to [this document](https://github.com/meganz/sdk/blob/master/doc/source/api_usage.rst) there is logging in via e-mail in their API. The page doesn't render correctly in GitHub, but you'll need to figure out how to log in. They have an Android app example, but it looks like the API is all native code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing:

```
while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
```

to

```
while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) != null) {
```

Comment: `Incompatible types boolean and int` is what comes up here.